# How to Images Swatches on base of Colors in Product Details Page in Magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, magento2.4, color-swatches

I am trying to display Color Swatches on Product Details Page, But  i don't know why Color swatches are not showing in frontend on product details page. On category page in layer navigation it's showing fine. But How to i can display on product details page ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: by default it should show, if you are using custom theme just switch to luma for testing and see if swatches available or not.

Comment: Images are not swatching on base of color ?